# Failed validation in model Ruby Rails passing to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

So I'm doing a CSV import for TiProject model and I have a validation set up in the model such that it's looking to see if TiProject.protype exists in a list of Projecttype.protype.  It works and if it fails to validate it crashes, great.  Now, I also have a rescue in place so I can let people know, hey, your stuff didn't upload.  I'd like to call out specifically what validation it failed.  I just don't know how to access that errors.add(:base, "xyz") in the code below and get it to show up in the notice.

ti_project.rb

```
class TiProject < ActiveRecord::Base
validate :validate_protype

def validate_protype
  if Projecttype.find_by_protype(protype) == nil
  errors.add(:base, "Project type doesn't exist")
 end
end

def self.import(file)
 CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
   TiProject.create! row.to_hash
 end
end 
other stuffs.....
```

ti_project_controller.rb

```
class TiProjectsController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, :with => :rescueuploads

def index
 @tiprojects =TiProject.all

end


def import
  TiProject.import(params[:file])
  TiProject.checkforpidtc
  redirect_to ti_projects_path, notice: "Projects uploaded successfully"
end


def rescueuploads
  redirect_to ti_projects_path, notice: "Project upload ERROR"
end
other stuffs....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def rescueuploads(exception)
  @error = exception
  @error.class
  @error.message #this is your message error raised from your model
  redirect_to ti_projects_path, notice: @error.message
end
```

Comment: Thanks Pedro, I really appreciate that.  Works fantastic with multiple validation methods in the model. =)